# Send input array with jquery Post without submitting form

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I need to Post data to an url without submitting a form and reloading the page but I'm not too good with JQuery.  How would I execute something along the lines of this 
html:

```
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="stuff[]">
<input type="text" name="stuff[]">
<input type="text" name="stuff[]">
<input type="text" name="stuff[]">
<button onclick="send()">send</button>
```

JQuery:

```
function send() {
params= {'name': $('#name').val(), 'stuff': $('#stuff[]').val()};
$.post( "url/test", params );
}
```

Comment: so what is the error in this code?

Comment: it doesn't actually work, this is just what I would logically guess how to do it.

Comment: @Chaosjosh - I did a rollback on your last edit for 2 reasons: 1. it breaks my answer ;b . 2. You've created illegal HTML. You're not allowed to have multiple elements share the same id, but you're allowed to have multiple inputs share the same name.

Comment: @Amit Ok, makes sens :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the values in all inputs named "stuff[]" like this:

```
$('#stuff[]').map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get().join()
```

This will give you a string concatenating all values, separated by commas.

Use that inside your code like this:

```
function send() {
  params= {'name': $('#name').val(),
    'stuff': $('input[name="stuff[]"]').map(function() {
       return $(this).val(); }).get().join()};
  $.post( "url/test", params );
}
```

Comment: using this gives me a Syntax error, `unrecognized expression :#stuff[]`

Comment: @Chaosjosh - sorry, try now

Comment: Upon using `print_r($_POST)` I notice that the data is not actually sent in an array, is there a way to do this or should I just use PHP to fix this issue

Comment: @Chaosjosh Take a look at my answer. print_r($_POST) will work just fine with it.

Comment: @wrxsti I appreciate your help but unfortunately my application is a lot more complex than my code shows(simplified for sanity sake), Amit's answer was easiest to expand towards my code.  All i had to do was `getcsv()` the data and it worked fine.

Comment: @Chaosjosh No worries. :) Glad you found your solution.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally you could treat it closer to a traditional form and use the [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method.

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="stuff[]" />
    <input type="text" name="stuff[]" />
    <input type="text" name="stuff[]" />
    <input type="text" name="stuff[]" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('form[name="myForm"]').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // This prevents the form from actually submitting like a traditional form.
        var formData = $(this).serialize(); // Gathers the form field values
        $.post('url/test', formData, function(data){
            alert(data); // This is the callback that will handle the response from the server.
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xrouxsu6/). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use the a for loop to iterate through the elements and then put them all in an array.